# Char array at c++ and merge it with other

Tags: c++, arrays, sqlite

I want to add some variable to char array while creating it. How can I do this? `sqlite3_prepare_v2` need `char[]`. thanks

```
unsigned int keyid = 10;
char buffer2[] = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = " + keyid; // problem (convert to char and merge)
sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, buffer2, strlen(buffer2), &stmt, 0);
```

Comment: Use `std::string`. char[] don't have operator overloading for string concatenation. Then you can use the `std::c_str()` to get a const char*

Comment: Beware little Bobby tables ;-) http://xkcd.com/327/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be binding your parameter instead. This also prevents any potential for SQL injection attacks.

```
unsigned int keyid = 10;
const char buffer2[] = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = ?";
sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, buffer2, -1, &stmt, 0);
sqlite3_bind_int(&stmt, 1, keyid);
```

Comment: thanks, good solution for my situation. are you sure that `?` need to bind like `1` in `sqlite3_bind_int` and not like `0` ? ps. and is it true that binding really can prevent injections for situation if keyid is `string` and I will it with `bind_text` function ?

Comment: Yes, binding completely eliminates SQL injection. Yes, that is supposed to be a `1`. See [the documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/bind_blob.html).

Answer (score 2):

Put the string inside a `string` :)

```
std::string buffer2 = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = " + std::to_string(keyid);
sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, buffer2.c_str(), buffer2.length(), &stmt, 0);
```

Comment: `tostring` or `to_string`?

Answer (score 2):

Well the most obvious solution for C++ is to use `std::string`

```
std::string buffer2 = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = " + std::to_string(keyid);
sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, buffer2.c_str() , buffer2.size() , &stmt, 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could stream the different types since you are using C++

```
#include <sstream>
//...
std::stringstream buffer2;
buffer2 << "SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = " << keyid;
```

and then use the string's `c_str` where a c style string is needed.

```
buffer2.str().c_str()'
```

*but* since this is SQL, using parameters in your query is much better.

Answer (score 0):

Look into sprintf, eg

```
sprintf(buffer2, "SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = %d", keyID);
```

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sprintf/

Comment: Consider using `snprintf` so you can specify the maximum size of `buffer2`.